# Commit errors with SQLAlchemy/sqlite for concurrent processes

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to write a Python + SQLAlchemy application that uses a centralized sqlite database to store information about various files. I use checksums to verify that each file and/or file version is only stored once in the database, so I have a `UniqueConstraint` on the checksum column.

I am storing the file info in `DbFile` objects that I want to do further operations on. I created a static method called `New()` that will return a `DbFile` object. If the file already exists in the database, it will return that object, otherwise it will create a new one.

```
 import md5
 # Not shown: sqlalchemy imports

 Base = declarative_base()
 engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
 Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
 session = Session()

 class DbFile(Base):
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     filename = Column(String, nullable=False)
     checksum = Column(String, nullable=False)

     __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint('checksum'),)

     @staticmethod
     def New(filename):
          file_md5 = md5.md5(open(filename).read())
          checksum = file_md5.hexdigest()

     q = session.query(Files).filter(Files.checksum == checksum)
     if q.count() == 1:
         print "Loading existing file object from database"
         return q.one()

     dbfile = DbFile(filename=filename, checksum=checksum)
```

After loading a number of files I do a `session.commit()`. This works fine if just a single process is accessing the database, but if I kick off multiple python processes (from the command line), one of them will invariably abort with an `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError` complaining that unique key constraint was violated for the checksum. There's obviously a race condition going on between checking for existence and writing to the database, but I haven't found a good way to prevent it.

I've tried to trap the error around the `session.commit()` but sometimes the error is triggered by the `q.count()` statement. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: sqlite is not suitable for multi-process databases. Use MySQL or PostgreSQL or another client-server-based database.

Comment: its true sqlite is a bad choice for this kind of thing, but the same problem will be essentially present on any backend.  one approach is to try the INSERT of dbfile inside of a SAVEPOINT, then if it fails, you go back to the one that's loaded.  SQLite supports SAVEPOINT but the Python driver currently does not.  the other approach is to use SERIALIZABLE isolation with sqlite, which requires the recipe at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#serializable-transaction-isolation to work around still more bugs in the pysqlite driver (seeing a pattern here)?

Comment: I agree that sqlite isn't the best tool for the job, but I'm stuck with it for now because this application is running over a pretty heterogeneous set of systems, some of which don't even have MySQL or PostgreSQL installed. Anyway, the SERIALIZABLE option did help, along with some external file-locking for really big transactions (I know, a complete hack)

Comment: Just an update: I ended up biting the bullet and re-coding everything around PostgreSQL. All the concurrency issues went away, and I was able to remove all the hacks that tried to get around SQLite's lack of concurrency. Much cleaner and simpler now.